# How to make Eclipse Java Editor templates available in Groovy editor

Tags: eclipse, templates, groovy

Eclipse's code templates save a lot of time and typing (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates). I'd like to use them when editing Groovy code also.

Unfortunately, there is no "Groovy" option in the context dropdown (see below), and these templates do not show up in the list when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in the Groovy editor.

[image]

**Is there any way to make these template available when editing a file with the Groovy editor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to validate this now, but check this [link](http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+2.8.0+New+and+Noteworthy%3Fprint=1.html).  This works for the 2.8.0 version of the Groovy Eclipse plugin.

The Groovy templates are available at: **Preferences->Groovy->Editor->GroovyTemplates.**

Comment: This partially works. Looks like any existing templates are java have to be rewritten, as not all of the macros are for the templates available or the same as for Java. For instance, the "import" macro seems to be missing or not working.

Comment: Yes, the list of options in the templates is fairly small for Groovy compared to Java.  I believe these templates are saved in a file so it should be possible to copy the java template to a new file, edit and save for Groovy or import the additions/changes into the Groovy templates.